# Zoom in/out for drawn objects in vb

Tags: vb.net, zooming

vb. I represent large data (bigger than in the picture) in a small area in my program window 
I draw lines with points of small difference of x and y 
I just want to zoom a particular portion of the form where is the drawing 
I tried to put a picture box and draw my data in it and zoom but it fails [image]

```
Private Sub PictureBox_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseWheel 
If e.Delta <> 0 Then 
If e.Delta <= 0 Then 
If PictureBox1.Width < 500 Then Exit Sub 
Else If PictureBox1.Width > 2000 Then Exit Sub
End If 
PictureBox1.Width += CInt(PictureBox1.Width * e.Delta / 1000) 
PictureBox1.Height += CInt(PictureBox1.Height * e.Delta / 1000) 
End If
```

Comment: `I tried to put a picture box and draw my data in it and zoom but it fails` where is this code you are talking about if you don't mind? This way we can help take a look to see what maybe going wrong. If not it's really hard to tell and you may not get much help.

Comment: Private Sub PictureBox_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseWheel
        If e.Delta <> 0 Then
            If e.Delta <= 0 Then
                If PictureBox1.Width < 500 Then Exit Sub 'minimum 500?
            Else
                If PictureBox1.Width > 2000 Then Exit Sub 'maximum 2000?
            End If

            PictureBox1.Width += CInt(PictureBox1.Width * e.Delta / 1000)
            PictureBox1.Height += CInt(PictureBox1.Height * e.Delta / 1000)
        End If

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code there instead. It's almost impossible to read from the comments.

Comment: @VisualVincent done

Comment: Zooming something is actually scaling it. If what you show is a picture, you would have to multiply that picture's width and height by the zoom factor (i.e the factor for 200% is 2, the factor for 150% is 1.5). If what you are showing is something you draw using GDI+ (`Graphics.Draw***()`) you would have to calculate, for each thing you draw, how big it should be and its point of origin.

Comment: I'm not really sure how the `e.Delta` works, but I'd recommend you to create a variable for the zoom factor which you change when you scroll, then change the size of the image/picture box/whatever using that variable.

Comment: @VisualVincent I managed to do it my friend by making the drawing as a bitmap and then scaling it [the idea was there](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_zoom_big_bitmap.html)